# ZXCT1084 Current sensor does not provide output signal

Tags: current, current-measurement, high-side

I am trying to create some kind of on/off switch, which would disable one sensor if the other is plugged in. I was thinking of creating up-side current sensing circuit, which would send voltage level to a transistor switch.
From sensors datasheet, I managed to find, that it consumes ~3 mA when in active mode. Then I created current sensing circuit, I used ZXCT1084 since I have worked with them previously. I was using fixed 25 gain variant, so did some calculations and made this LTspice model:

[image]

The idea is to get around 1.5 V at the Vout when 3 mA is being drawn, this means that new sensor was connected and previous sensor should be disconnected, which is being done using transistor switch.
The problem is that in the real circuit I don't get any voltage, I tried experimenting with a 10 Ω resistor as a load which would draw around 330 mA current and on Vout I got around 2.70 V.
LTspice was not able to simulate this, I am guessing because V_out max = V_s-1V, since my voltage is 3.3 V max I can get from V_out is 2.3 V.
But this does not answer my question, why am I not getting anything when load is drawing 3 mA?
Did I missed something in current sensor datasheet?